Time series Forecast
I’ve been meaning to ask an expert in the field of forecasting a burning question about a forecasting project am working on. I’m building a model to forecast groundwater thickness, and am tasked to use exogenous variables like surface temperature, precipitation etc. Given that using seasonal and calendar features as exogenous variables are always available during the forecast horizon but exogenous variables like surface temperature, precipitation ain’t. Do I have to recursively forecast for exogenous variables like surface temperature and precipitation before I can proceed to forecast for groundwater thickness? I’d extremely appreciate your input. Look forward to hearing from you soon. Thanks

If you are using this data in the model, you will also need it during forecasting. How you get them is a different question, do you have some forecasts for these exogenous variables?
